# Why is this binary state format so much more efficient than a non-binary one?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am teaching myself Deep Q Learning (and machine learning in general) using python and tensorflow to play Snake. My initial learning came mostly from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-teach-an-ai-to-play-games-deep-reinforcement-learning-28f9b920440a). I have rewritten it in my own coding style and it is working well.

Now I am experimenting with different parameters and state information. The state for my game is an array of 11 values that looks like this:

```
0 - Danger 1 step ahead
1 - Danger 1 step on the right
2 - Danger 1 step on the left
3 - Snake is moving left
4 - Snake is moving right
5 - Snake is moving up
6 - Snake is moving down
7 - Food is on the left
8 - Food is on the right
9 - Food is on the upper side
10 - Food is on the lower side
```

All of these values are binary, either 0 or 1. To experiment, I wanted to switch out elements 3 through 6 with the constants I use for direction.

```
DIR_UP = 1
DIR_RIGHT = 2
DIR_DOWN = 3
DIR_LEFT = 4
```

So the state object would be an array of 8 elements, element 3 being non-binary:

```
0 - Danger 1 step ahead
1 - Danger 1 step on the right
2 - Danger 1 step on the left
3 - Snake movement direction
4 - Food is on the left
5 - Food is on the right
6 - Food is on the upper side
7 - Food is on the lower side
```

To me, this seems to have all the same information but in a different format, but the DQN apparently doesn't think so. After 150 training iterations on the first format, I get a competent snake that can regularly score 40 or more. To get the same scores on format 2 I needed to run 800 iterations with a slower epsilon decay. And in testing (without any randomness) it still takes indirect routes and needlessly crashes into the wall now and then, which I thought would have been weeded out.

So my main question is: what am I failing to understand about state format that makes my first so much more efficient than my second?

And sub-questions: are states supposed to be binary? What if I have to account for something like distance that can't be easily represented that way?

Thanks so much for you time and input!

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the state space by introducing non-binary options. This increases the complexity the model has to learn to reach the same level of performance.

In particular, you are creating a nested structure which makes it more difficult to assign reward credit to a specific option. The hierarchical options are "Should the snake move?" then "If yes, which direction?" make it slower to assign credit to the directional movement. A flat structure "Should the the snake move up?" allows credit to be more directly assigned to that decision.